# Passing variable from one function to another function in same controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

I need to pass a id from a fuction to other function, i tried this way but i cant get the result. Can anyone spot the mistake and give me a solution. This is the exact code i am using

```
public function splstaff($id)
{
    $staff = DB::select("SELECT staff_id FROM special_labs WHERE sno={$id}");
    $this->splstafflist($staff);
}

public function splstafflist($staff)
{
    $data=DB::connection('mysql3')->select("SELECT MD5(CONCAT(a.staff_id,a.dob,a.cat_id))  staffid,a.staff_id,a.dep_id,
     LOWER(CONCAT(a.legend,' ',a.staff_name))staff_name,a.photo,b.desi_name,IFNULL(c.degree,'')degree,b.desi_orderno,
     IFNULL(MIN(sp.date_promotion),a.doj) doj FROM staff_personal_copy a LEFT JOIN staff_designationmaster b ON a.desi_id=b.desi_id
     LEFT JOIN staff_qualification_view c ON c.staff_id=a.staff_id LEFT JOIN (camps.staff_promotion sp INNER JOIN staff_designationmaster sd
     ON sp.to_designation=sd.desi_id AND sp.status>0 INNER JOIN staff_desigmaster sd1 ON sp.from_design=sd1.desi_id AND
     sd1.desi_orderno!=sd.desi_orderno ) ON sp.staff_id=a.staff_id AND b.desi_orderno=sd.desi_orderno WHERE a.staff_id IN ('{$staff}')
     AND a.status=1 AND a.cat_id=1 GROUP BY a.staff_id,sd.desi_orderno ORDER BY b.desi_orderno,doj,a.staff_id");
    return view('research.labs.staff',['splfac'=>$data]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uptade the first function adding `return` intruction like this:

```
public function splstaff($id)
{
    $staff = DB::select("SELECT staff_id FROM special_labs WHERE sno={$id}");
    return $this->splstafflist($staff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might write your fist line of code with less complicated way ...

```
$value = DB::table('special_labs')->where('sno',$id)->pluck('staff_id')->first();
 return   $this->splstafflist($value);
```

the problem was in this line:

```
 $staff = DB::select("SELECT staff_id FROM special_labs WHERE sno={$id}");
```

you did not use get() method so the result will be a query builder, and when you got the result it will be an array even if it has only one result ...
so I recommend using pluck to take only the column you want and first to get the value from the array result ..

Comment: This is returning the value if ID which has been passed from the url